# What is the difference between first hand and hands-on?

Tags: difference, adjective-phrases

For example, which one fits in this context better?

> Working as a teacher, she has **hands-on experience** with suspected drug user students.
>   Working as a teacher, she has **first hand experience** with suspected drug user students.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Hands on" means there is/was a physical interaction. You might have hands-on experience baking cookies, for example.

First hand means "directly." For example, a person who directly worked with drug using students as opposed to someone who read a report the first person wrote about their experience. The person who read the report would be said to have "second hand" knowledge.

Comment: But wouldn’t a person with _first hand experience_ likely have _hands-on experience_ as well?

Comment: @JR Perhaps not - you can experience something firsthand without direct interaction, for example at a sporting event.

Comment: And for the specific example the OP gave, I would suggest 'first hand' over 'hands-on' because they didn't specify a specific action.  "Working as a teacher, she has hands-on experience **teaching** suspected drug user students." would be better than "Working as a teacher, she has hands-on experience **with** suspected drug user students."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have also seen [hands-on used in a not physical way too](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101901/how-do-you-say-hands-on-experience-with-this-technology-to-an-interviewer), are these exceptional?

Comment: @user373 In your linked example, the person is saying they have hands-on experience with "a technology" which is vague but still concrete and would allow someone to say "hands-on." Maybe it's an electronic device (very much "hands-on") or even just a particular piece of software (not literally "hands-on" but something you'd interact with via computer hardware). And, of course, people do misuse words/phrases, too ;-)